# MongoDB PHP getting data from multi collections

Tags: php, mongodb, nosql

I have 2 collections

- Users - name,points,clan(ObjectID)
- Clans - name

So I need to get Clans points with this logic:

Sum of all user points in the same clans, divide clan users count, group by clans, order by total points and limit 10. Shortly I need to get best 10 clans.

But I couldn't create query. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform two queries and iterate through them in your code. There are no joins in MongoDB. Alternatively you could embed a Clan document in your User document so that you could query on just your user collection and get all the information you need.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But how can i embed Clans to Users document? Can i use sub query in PHP with MongoDB aggregate framework ?